# Apply opacity to hidden overflow

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Is there a way to apply opacity to a hidden overflow in CSS? I have a div that must use `overflow: hidden` property but I wanted to apply opacity to the hidden elements.

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
.slick-list:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The slick plugin uses a class called `.slick-list` That class is responsible for hiding sliders from the main container. As part of design requirements I need to display the hidden slides using opacity property. Is that possible? I thought that if I apply the opacity property to the `::after` element it would work but apparently is not taking any effect.

**[Check my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/76/)**

Comment: Have you tested this:.slick-slide[aria-hidden="true"] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

Comment: Things that are hidden are invisible, so they will remain hidden if you apply opacity to them. If anything, they will become _more_ invisible, since they will be transparent as well as hidden. So that's not the solution. In the fiddle you're not making it very clear what you want to achieve, by the way.

Comment: @MrLister sorry if it wasn't very clear. Please check this version: http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/77/ it shows all the elements but with the horizontal scroll. This is what I am trying to do but without the horizontal scroll.

Comment: If you don't want a horizontal scrollbar, all you need to do is set overflow-x:hidden on the _body_. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5eceg5yd/78/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this. Basically adding a full width div to the body and adding the carousel inside that div worked really well.

```
.container {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slick-list {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

**[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/80/)**

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't use `opacity` on hidden elements, they can't be visible so `overflow` must be set to `visible` in order to achieve what you desire.

Comment: Yeah I've done this already. But unfortunately it displays the horizontal scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/77/

Comment: That horizontal slider is in JS Fiddle, because it exceeds the width of its output area

Answer (score 0):

A hidden object cannot have opacity as it is not visible , you should set your `overflow` to `visible` or any comfortable options and apply opacity